# Graph Web application authentication single sign on

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I saw some information about single sign on in combination with the azure ad. Does that mean I can create a web application that's using the graph api (Calendar , Contact) and using the single sign on for a pleasant user experience. I'm aware of the fact that the user should autorize the application to access his/her private data.

I have already looked on

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-sso-integrate-saas-apps/

https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/active-directory-appssoaccess-whatis/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can register an application with Azure AD and use it to leverage the user's identity in the Microsoft cloud (for work and school accounts and for personal accounts) to support single sign-on. In addition that same application can then be authorized to access their data (mail, calendar, files, contacts, etc.) via the Microsoft Graph API.